# How do I redirect to a website using MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am having a hard time figuring out how to redirect to an outside source.

in my code, I have

`<%= Html.ActionLink("New Name Search", "Index") %>` 
which will allow me to navigate within the code.

how do I redirect to ...google for example?

Answer (score 14):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: considering HTML.actionLink produces a html action link I'd say that this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the ActionLink helper is to generate links that will direct the user to a controller action that you've defined.

If you want to navigate the user to an outside source you should just use a regular anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Redirect("http://google.com/");
```

(It's not really MVC-specific, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting from your controller (or action filter, etc.) you can use the `RedirectResult` as your `ActionResult` type:

```
RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
```

This is essentially doing a `Response.Redirect`, but is the preferred way of sticking with ASP.NET MVC conventions.

If you are just creating a link inside a `View`, just use `<a href="http://www.google.com">Click to go to Google</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

"Redirecting" means many things.

If you just want to show a link that redirects the user to another URL you can use the anchor tag normally in you templates.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Now, if you want to redirect the user within the controller, call the [Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

```
Result("http://www.google.com");
```